# How can I get my TSQL Stored Procedure to return data?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am starting out with "baby steps" with a Stored Procedure which will end up being somewhat complex. All I want to do at first is to create a temp table, populate a few of the fields with some bogus values, and then have the table be returned from the SP when it is called. Here it is:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[priceVarianceTest]
    @Unit varchar(25),
    @BegDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime 
AS 

DECLARE @Week1End datetime = DATEADD(Day, 6, @BegDate);
DECLARE @Week2Begin datetime = DATEADD(Day, 7, @BegDate);

create table #temp1
(
    Unit varchar(50),
    MemberNo varchar(42),
    MemberItemCode varchar(42),
    ShortName varchar(25),
    ItemCode varchar(50),
    WVItem varchar(25),
    WVItemCode varchar(25),
    WVDescription varchar(250),
    Week1Usage varchar(25),
    Week2Usage varchar(25),
    UsageVariance varchar(25),
    Week1Price varchar(25),
    Week2Price varchar(25),
    PriceVariance varchar(25),
    PercentageOfPriceVariance varchar(42)
)

-- now try to add some data and return it:
Update #temp1 set
Unit = 'LOS CARNEROS',
MemberNo = '1289',
MemberItemCode = '76Trombones';

select * from #temp1;
```

And here is what it is rendered as when I execute it from Server Explorer (after I enter 'bla' and a couple of dates when prompted for the parameter vals):

```
USE [CPSData]
GO

DECLARE @return_value Int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[priceVarianceTest]
        @Unit = N'bla',
        @BegDate = N'2015-01-01',
        @EndDate = N'2016-01-01'

SELECT  @return_value as 'Return Value'

GO
```

I was hoping the "select *" would return some data, but all I get in the Results pane is:

```
    Return Value
----------------
1   0
```

Why does it not return something more like:

```
Unit        MemberNo    MemberItemCode  ShortName   . . .
----        --------    --------------  ---------   -----
LOS CARNEROS    1289        76Trombones Null        . . .
```

?

What need I do to get meaningful (albeit admittedly contrived) data back from the SP?

Comment: You never insert any data to the temporary table. The stored procedure contains an UPDATE, not an INSERT.

Comment: Oh, so the Update doesn't act as an Upsert? Alright, I'll try inserting instead of updating (for the first round).

Comment: Update does not add any new rows, it only changes existing ones.  Use INSERT to add rows to your temp table.

Comment: An UPDATE is an UPDATE. ANSI hase MERGE for upserts, some databases have *special syntax* for them but **no** database confuses a plain UPDATE for UPSERT. Just imagine the data bugs that would happen if it did

Comment: BTW, that update statement means "Replace all data in the table with identical values" in all databases. If you used this in a real database you would lose all data

Comment: BTW 2, the # indicates a temp table that will exist on the next iteration of the stored procedure.  Either use a declare table, or check if the table exists and drop it if necessary.

Comment: @Steven or create a table-typed variable. Takes the same amount of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Update #temp1 set
Unit = 'LOS CARNEROS',
MemberNo = '1289',
MemberItemCode = '76Trombones';
```

Will not work if there are no rows present.

You need to use INSERT rather than UPDATE:

```
INSERT INTO #temp1 (Unit,MemberNo,MemberItemCode)
VALUES('LOS CARNEROS','1289','76Trombones')
```

A `MERGE` might be what you looking for if you want to be able to do both. But since you are recreating the table within your stored proc then I dont see you using update any time.